# Unable to publish to group cortana skill

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

[image: Error Message]

While trying to publish to group getting the above error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what it is you are trying to accomplish and include any available code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowledge.store and the ability to publish went down yesterday. We are actively working to bring it back online.

Comment: Please try again as the last deployment was rolled-back.

Comment: If the problem persists, please post the HTTP headers for the failing request.